# Authenticate second web application with first web application using current user

Tags: web-application, application-pages

I have two different web applications "A" and "B". I have one user who has permission in both applications.

How can I login into "B" from "A" using application page silently with current user who have permission in both web applications?

Comment: If you are on SharePoint 2013 SharePoint Token Services should do the work.

Comment: Yes, my environment is sharepoint 2013 but how can this possible? can you provide steps?